# LUA compile error with Visual 2010 "external symbol "struct lua_State * __cdecl luaL_newstate(void)"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lua

I use Lua ver 5.2.3 with visual studio 2010 , when i compile  code below

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>                          
#include <stdio.h> 

void main()
{
    lua_State *luaState = luaL_newstate();

}
```

I got error

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct lua_State * __cdecl luaL_newstate(void)" (?luaL_newstate@@YAPAUlua_State@@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
```

Could you please give me any advice about this .
Thank !!!

Comment: You need to link with the Lua library.

Comment: I already link Lua library .But still error

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866947/lua-module-with-visual-studio

Comment: I compiled  the LUA library for myself from  source code ( lua.org). I did it as static library. I config all success . But linking error . i think it come from visual studio 2010 . On visual 2008 it doesn't occur.

Comment: Updated your question to show linker configuration (can paste XML of vcxproj) and the output when you build.

Comment: I have  found the reason . It must use extern . I fix by use this code extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
} Everything ok

Answer (score 8):

This is a result of C++ "name mangling".  See how there are strange characters in this term:

```
?luaL_newstate@@YAPAUlua_State@@XZ
```

You have choices:

Change the file extension of this file to .c instead of .cpp, so that it runs through the C compiler instead of the C++ compiler (caveat: depending on compiler)

or

Add extern "C" around the includes like this:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
}
```

or

```
#include "lua.hpp"
```

In the last case, that header is included with the 5.2 release. It does what I wrote in option 2 for you.